# Linq with join need distinct rows by ID

Tags: c#, linq, model-view-controller

I am getting multiple rows of combination. I need Unique  Vendor rows with unique VendorCod.

Code:

```
IQueryable<VendorModel> vendors = (from vendor in _context.Vendor
                               join vp in _context.VendorProduct on vendor.Pkid equals vp.VendorId
                               where vp.ProductId == ProductId

                               select new VendorModel()
                               {
                                   VendorId = vendor.Pkid,
                                   Name = vendor.Name,
                                   VendorCode = vendor.VendorCode,
                                   FacilityId = 0,
                                   ClientId = 0,
                                   Active = vendor.Active ?? false,
                                   UpdatedAt = vendor.UpdatedAt,
                                   DeletedAt = vendor.DeletedAt
                               });
```

Comment: Are you joining with the correct Id values? Is Pkid conceptually same as VendorId? Can you show sample data from both Vendor and VendorProduct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many products for a vendors, so you have to apply appropriate predicate and no joins are needed.

Via navigation property:

```
var vendors = 
   from vendor in _context.Vendor
   where vendor.Products.Any(vp => vp.ProductId == ProductId)
   select new VendorModel
   {
       VendorId = vendor.Pkid,
       Name = vendor.Name,
       VendorCode = vendor.VendorCode,
       FacilityId = 0,
       ClientId = 0,
       Active = vendor.Active ?? false,
       UpdatedAt = vendor.UpdatedAt,
       DeletedAt = vendor.DeletedAt
   };
```

Or if you do not have navigation property:

```
var vendors = 
   from vendor in _context.Vendor
   where _context.VendorProduct.Any(vp => vendor.Pkid == vp.VendorId && vp.ProductId == ProductId)
   select new VendorModel
   {
       VendorId = vendor.Pkid,
       Name = vendor.Name,
       VendorCode = vendor.VendorCode,
       FacilityId = 0,
       ClientId = 0,
       Active = vendor.Active ?? false,
       UpdatedAt = vendor.UpdatedAt,
       DeletedAt = vendor.DeletedAt
   };
```

Comment: FYI, small typo in second query: `VendorProduts`...

Answer (score 0):

You will need to group your products and check if any match the code

```cs
IQueryable<VendorModel> vendors = (from vendor in _context.Vendor
                               join vp in _context.VendorProduct on vendor.Pkid equals vp.VendorId into vpg
                               where vpg.Any(vp => vp.ProductId == ProductId)

                               select new VendorModel()
                               {
                                   VendorId = vendor.Pkid,
                                   Name = vendor.Name,
                                   VendorCode = vendor.VendorCode,
                                   FacilityId = 0,
                                   ClientId = 0,
                                   Active = vendor.Active ?? false,
                                   UpdatedAt = vendor.UpdatedAt,
                                   DeletedAt = vendor.DeletedAt
                               });
```